# Instant run does not work with the android studio 3.3 update

Tags: android, android-studio, instant-run

So far I have used instant run without any problem in a Nexus 5 with android 7.
Yesterday I updated Android Studio to stable version 3.3
Since then, Instant Run does not work, I always get the following warning:

[image]

Selecting the option to uninstall the previous version, it does not start, because the warning of "error installing the APK"

If I deactivate instant Run everything works perfectly again.

About the code or configuration, nothing has been changed.

Of course, I also manually uninstalled the previous version before the initial compilation.

I have read about it in this forum, but I can not find a solution to this specific problem case.

It happens to someone else? Any solution?

Comment: just clean the project and invalidate cache and restart it will surely work.

Comment: Uninstall Build App from all User of Your Phone And Try Again.

Comment: I have tried the two answers, without success

Comment: @Sergio76 This may be a long shot but try a new project that uses Android 8.1 just add two numbers and transfer the result to another Activity (page) If you can try to un-install the AS 3.3 and go back to Ver 3.2.1 and do not uninstall the previous version

Comment: Same problem here. I think it's a bug. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217518/after-upgrade-to-android-studio-3-3-on-mac-run-stuck-on-installing-apk-and-do)