# After upgrade to Android Studio 3.3 on Mac, run Stuck on “Installing APK” and doesn't deploy to connected device

Tags: android, android-studio

After upgrading to latest Android Studio version 3.3 from stable channel on Mac machine, now when I press run with a connected device it builds successfully and keeps telling "Installing apks" but after taking sometime, It is neither installing nor showing the error. Have tried also on the emulator and same issue. Could any one tell how to solve this problem ?

I have tried restart, clean, rebuild and all didn't work.

Comment: Try disabling Instant Run to see if it works.
People are reporting problems with it after the update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217170/instant-run-does-not-work-with-the-android-studio-3-3-update

Comment: when tried to disable instant run, I got this message when run **Session 'app': Error Installing APK**
if enable it again, I face the original issue of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2 days of struggling I found the issue was related to an installed software which was using port 5556 and 5557 so using commands related to ADB didn't work and although it was installed before but it seems to have an issue with Android Studio 3.3
And if someone comes to run into the same issue, here are the steps you can follow to check on your Mac:
1- First open the "Network Utility" then go to "Port Scan" tab to check for open ports as in the screenshot
[port scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8d17.png)
2- if you found some ports in the range used by the ADB simulators as I found in the previous image then open the terminal and write the below command to check what is listening to that port
`sudo lsof -i :5556
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    9264  amr   12u  IPv6 0x4225de633b747c4d      0t0  TCP *:freeciv (LISTEN)` 
The second column in the output is the process ID 
3- Now from the terminal write the below command to locate the software related to the process ID
`ps -ef 9264
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501  9264     1   0  2:42PM ??         0:00.56 /Applications/Videostream.app/Contents/Resources/node /Applications/Videostream.app/Contents/Resources/lib/index.js`
4- Try to stop this process or as in my case I had to uninstall the software completely to solve Android Studio issue.