# How to fix instant app with Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I updated to Android Studio 3.3. and also, all SDKs too. Now I cannot run the instant version of my app. **I get the following error:**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Words:Words:writeAndroidDebugFeatureApplicationId'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected configuration ':Words:Words:androidDebugFeatureMetadataValues' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.ApplicationIdWriterTask.fullTaskAction(ApplicationIdWriterTask.kt:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:672)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$4.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:338)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:312)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$5(CacheStep.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep$$Lambda$483/988154824.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep$$Lambda$416/111798206.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    ... 40 more
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Tue Jan 15 12:44:45 CET 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2-all.zip
```

It works with the old Android Studio Gradle-4.6 but when I try to roll back I get the message : ERROR: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.6.

**dependencies**

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'

    api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1';

    // Required by Facebook network
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.1.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.0.0"
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':ASCore'
include ":Words:Words"
include ":Words:WordsInstant"
include ':Words:WordsInstall'
```

top-level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules .

buildscript {
    ext {
        /* Build versions */
        minSdkVersion = 16
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**base module build.gradle**

```
apply from: '../../feature.gradle'
apply from: '../version.gradle'


android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Feature Version = Instant ap version
        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName VERSION_NAME
        resValue "string", "app_id", "XXXXX"
        manifestPlaceholders.appClass = APPLICATION_ID + ".App"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**instant module build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'
apply from: '../version.gradle'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId APPLICATION_ID
        manifestPlaceholders.appClass = APPLICATION_ID + ".App"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "$APPLICATION_ID-$VERSION_CODE")
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation project(':Words:Words')
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    flavorDimensions "type"
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        //multiDexEnabled true // enable for the MediationTestSuite
        resValue "string", "AS_BUILD_TIMESTAMP", "\"" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\""
    }

    signingConfigs {
        AsgardKey {
            keyAlias 'XXX'
            keyPassword 'XXX'
            storeFile file("XXX")
            storePassword 'XXX'
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
        AsgardKeyDev {
            keyAlias 'XXX'
            keyPassword 'XXX'
            storeFile file("XXX")
            storePassword 'XXX'
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "bool", "IS_DEBUG", "true"
            signingConfig XXX
        }
        release {
            resValue "bool", "IS_DEBUG", "false"
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "$rootProject.projectDir/proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig XXX
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        play {
            dimension 'type'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_PRO', 'false'
        }
    }

    bundle {
        density.enableSplit = true
        abi.enableSplit = true
        language {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }


    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                outputFileName = "${applicationId}-${versionCode}-${variant.flavorName}.apk"
            }
        }

        if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
            variant.assemble.doLast {
                copy {
                    from variant.mappingFile
                    into variant.outputs[0].outputFile.parent
                    rename { String fileName ->
                        "${applicationId}-${versionCode}-${variant.flavorName}-mapping.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':ASCore')
}

apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/dependencies.gradle"
```

**feature.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    baseFeature true

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "AS_BUILD_TIMESTAMP", "\"" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\""
    }

    signingConfigs {
        AsgardKey {
            keyAlias 'XXXX'
            keyPassword 'XXXX'
            storeFile file("XXXX")
            storePassword 'XXXX'
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
        AsgardKeyDev {
            keyAlias 'XXXX'
            keyPassword 'XXXX'
            storeFile file("XXXX")
            storePassword 'XXXX'
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "bool", "IS_DEBUG", "true"
            signingConfig XXXX
        }
        release {
            resValue "bool", "IS_DEBUG", "false"
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "$rootProject.projectDir/proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig XXXX
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        android {
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_PRO', 'false'
        }
    }


    bundle {
        density.enableSplit = true
        abi.enableSplit = true
        language {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':ASCore')
}

apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/dependencies.gradle"
```

How I can fix this issue?

Regards
Ronald

Comment: What is your gradle plugin version `com.android.tools.build:gradle`

Comment: I use version 3.3.0 and com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 from the repositories google and jcenter and set following build versions      minSdkVersion = 16
targetSdkVersion = 28
compileSdkVersion = 28
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"

Comment: post your project level `build.gradle` code

Comment: I added my gradle files ASCore is my base library.

Comment: Did you tried with distributionUrl 4.10.1: `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: 4.10.1 also generate the same error. with com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0 every thing works fine

Comment: Please try as follows

File >Invalidate Caches / Restart
Deleting .idea folder
Running gradlew clean
Re-import the project

Comment: the error still happens

Comment: Have you checked [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217170/instant-run-does-not-work-with-the-android-studio-3-3-update) citing that Android Studio 3.3 has a bug?

Comment: The installation on a device work but the build process has the issue. Currently I try to create an aab package and let this run as instant app. I have to add 
          xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution" and <dist:module dist:instant="true" /> to the manifest. It works but I get the warnings that this deployment is experimental and unsupported. If im ready with this update I will try to upload it to Google Play. If it is working I will post my solution here.

Answer (score 1):

## My current working solution

Remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from my base module. In the old version was this necessary to get firebase analytics working.

Now I use the aab package format with instant app support:

https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle

and modify my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ... xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution">
    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Android Studio show the warning

> The option setting 'android.injected.deploy.instant-app=true' is
>   experimental and unsupported.

but it works with Google Play Store, Play Services and Firebase :-)

Regards
Ronald